# Derivations of Forward and Reverse KL Divergence equations

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, kullback-leibler

In the Forward KL, the entropy has disappeared and in the Reverse KL, the entropy has a plus sign, why are they so?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

1. The entropy does not depend on the theta-parameter. We can therefore discard it in the optimization procedure as it wont change the argmin
2. The author multiplied the whole expression by -1 and is now looking for the argmax instead of argmin.